# mysql problem with select group by month and sum year

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have this table

[image: table structure with data]

so i need sum by year and month.. like this:

[image: output]

now i have select:

```
SELECT month(date_sales) AS MONTH,
   SUM(amount)
FROM crm_sales
WHERE crm_sales.repsa_company_id='473'
  AND crm_sales.partner_id='12'
  AND year(date_sales)='2019'
GROUP BY month(date_sales)
```

Comment: And the nature of your problem is?

Comment: Your query looks for year 2019 your data only contains 2020 - please add representative sample data and expected output as text to the question

Comment: Sorry. here is better sample data: https://puu.sh/GRMFD/6a148074cc.png
so i need this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwwtn.png) - sorry I can't describe it (I need to display the amount by year for each month  - in this form).

Comment: We prefer sample data as text so that we can use it when providing a solution - images we cannot use and I personally don't want an imugr account.

Comment: @P.Salmon problem is that i dont know how show sum others years not only 2019

Comment: Search for conditional aggregation.